# Can the data "visited-number of days" be known/displayed publicly for any user?

Tags: support, users, data-explorer

If we visit any user's profile it will show data like:

- Member for (Years; Months)
- profile views
- last seen
- visited- X days; Y consecutive.

For my profile in particular it shows that i am a member for 2 years and 1 month (which must be view-able to all as i can also view the same for others) and that i visited 601 days; 10 consecutive.

[image]

The last data (visited) is not publicly shown ( I can not see the same for any other users except mine for example).

Questions:

1. Can this data be known for any arbitrary user?
2. Can the moderators of our site see this data for all users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It is not available for a normal user. It is available for you and moderators only.

For normal users or when logged out

[image: Profile activity info of a profile]

For the user when logged in the same as you uploaded in the question.

For moderators, extra info is shown due to the gems they possess.

[image: profile for moderators.]

<sup>Imsge taken from [MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122989/357396)</sup>

SEDE also doesn't give the consecutive days visited ([Confirmed on Meta Stack exchange also](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293014/357396)) .